# Convert the M and K of an Currency to integers in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with column of type `StringType()`. The values in these money columns contains abbreviations like `K` and `M`.

I would like to remove 'K' and 'M' and multiple them either by 1000 or 1000000 for K/M respectively. I tried creating a function and use it to add a new column in the dataframe. I keep getting the following error

> ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and',
> '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean
> expressions.

The Column values are as follows:

[image]

```
def convertall(ReleaseClause):
  if ReleaseClause == None:
    return 0
  elif expr("substring(ReleaseClause,-1,length(ReleaseClause))")=='K':
    remove_euro=expr("substring(ReleaseClause,2,length(ReleaseClause))")
    remove_K=translate(remove_euro,'K','')
    remove_Kint=remove_K.cast(IntegerType())*lit(1000)
    return remove_Kint
  elif expr("substring(ReleaseClause,-1,length(ReleaseClause))")=='M':
    remove_euro=expr("substring(ReleaseClause,2,length(ReleaseClause))")
    remove_M=translate(remove_euro,'M','')
    remove_Mint=remove_M.cast(IntegerType())*lit(1000000)
    return remove_Mint
  else:
    return ReleaseClause
```

Comment: Use pyspark [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) function instead of python if-else-statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following code converts the data using F.when() function. Before that, the string is split into letters, then M/K symbol is extracted, as well as the amount to be multiplied. This solution assumes the string size remains the same and the  position of M/K symbol as well as the amount data is not variable  across rows.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [("$12.3M",),
        ("$23.4K",),
        ("$12.5M",),
        ("$22.3K",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["ReleaseClause"])

df_ans = (df
        .select("ReleaseClause", 
                (F.split("ReleaseClause",'').alias("split")))
        .withColumn("scale", F.col("split")[5])
        .withColumn("amount", 
               F.concat(F.col("split")[1], F.col("split")[2], 
                        F.col("split")[3], F.col("split")[4])
               .cast("double"))
        .withColumn("scaled", F.when(F.col("scale")=="K", 
                                         F.col("amount")*1000)
                               .when(F.col("scale")=="M", 
                                         F.col("amount")*1000000))
```

This produces output as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could check if value contains `K` or `M`, extract the number and multiply.

Example:

```py
data = [("$12.3M",), ("$23.4K",), ("$12.5M",), ("$22.3K",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=["ReleaseClause"])
df = df.withColumn(
    "result",
    F.when(
        F.col("ReleaseClause").contains("K"),
        F.regexp_extract(F.col("ReleaseClause"), "(\d+(.\d+)?)", 1).cast(DoubleType())
        * 1000,
    )
    .when(
        F.col("ReleaseClause").contains("M"),
        F.regexp_extract(F.col("ReleaseClause"), "(\d+(.\d+)?)", 1).cast(DoubleType())
        * 1000000,
    )
    .cast(IntegerType()),
)
```

Result:

```
+-------------+--------+                                                        
|ReleaseClause|result  |
+-------------+--------+
|$12.3M       |12300000|
|$23.4K       |23400   |
|$12.5M       |12500000|
|$22.3K       |22300   |
+-------------+--------+
```